# std::bitset - how to iterate "set" (or "not set") bits?

Tags: c++, stl, bitset

I'm using bitset in my code:

```
std::bitset<MAX_INSTRUMENTS_NUMBER_IN_SYSTEM> updatedInstruments;
```

Often I need to iterate only values that "set" (or "not set"), this is how I do that:

```
for (int instrumentId = 0; instrumentId < MAX_INSTRUMENTS_NUMBER_IN_SYSTEM; instrumentId++) {
    if (!updatedInstruments[instrumentId]) {
        continue;
    }
    // work
}
```

Can this iteration be improved to be more readable and possibly faster?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can exploit the contiguity of set bits in your code using `std::bitset`: the interface doesn't provide anything to help in this task, and there's no legal way to access the underlying storage and work directly with it.<sup>1</sup>

If instead you can afford to change container, you can find several better alternatives. [Here](http://bmagic.sourceforge.net/enum.html) for example is a bitset-like structure that provides "enumerators" for active bits (it seems mostly like working with spans on images), and in the duplicate I linked above there are several other suggestions for data structures more specialized for this use case.

---

1. Previously I supposed that iterators might have yielded some performance advantage, but turns out `std::bitset` doesn't have iterators :-o Also, a similar test performed on `std::vector<bool>` (which should pack bits more or less the same way) gave a ~2x slowdown using iterators both with g++ and clang++.

Comment: How do iterators gain performance?

Comment: I'm not saying it's guaranteed, but I can see some small optimization. Using an index requires re-calculation of the position in the underlying storage, bit shift and mask, while an iterator could cache, say, a word (that may go into a register) and just shift there until the next word is needed. I just pulled this out of my mind, but in general when dealing with containers where indexing is more complicated than pointer sum + dereference it's better to work with iterators, since they are optimized for traversal.

Comment: That makes sense in general but for a sequence container I'm not so sure. Can add vs inc really be noticeable here?

Comment: When I'm on a real computer I'll do some tests. OTOH, it's clear that here the real optimization (keeping the underlying data structure) would be to skip completely all-zero or all-set bytes (or even words) and in "mixed" bytes be able to do the shifts (to reach the "border" of each span) without all the clunky conversions to bool. This requires a container that either provides some support for a span-like interface, or exposes its internals a bit more.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I just tried to perform the benchmark but... jeez, `std::bitset` doesn't even have iterators! So I guess my point is completely moot...